# src files are not showing in my Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

All the packages, projects, source files were showing on the left of my Eclipse. Suddenly all the files are not showing anymore.

How to get them back?

My Eclipse window currently looks like this

[image: Eclipse currently looks like this]

Comment: I didn't work with Eclipse very often but did you try one of the buttons in the project view? Or just restarting Eclipse? Probably there's an option to reset the layout changes you've made.

Comment: Make a backup of everything, then reopen Eclipse using a different workspace and re-import the project into the Project Explorer.

Comment: Try to click on the filter arrow next to project-name/working-set name on left frame. Then click on top level elements and change working-set to project. Try this and it should work.

Comment: @PrabirGhosh  no sir, not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Window at the top in Eclipse.
2. Click on Show View
3. In Show View , select Package Explorer.

Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer.

Just follow the same process, if you by mistake close any of the view windows in Eclipse.

Comment: no Package Explorer is there. i have Project Explorer

Comment: Alt+Shift+Q, P,  this s a short cut for package explorer. Hold the first 3 keys and then press P. It'll open.

Comment: Or in show view, click on 'Other', then just type 'Package', package explorer will appear in suggestions.

Comment: for that i should have more than 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on the small  arrow next to project-name/working-set name on left frame (project explorer frame). Then click on "top level elements" and change "working-set" to "project". Try this and it should work.